# Segfault with asio standalone when classes in separate files

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

The below is as minimal of an example as I can get. It does need to be in separate files as that seems to be what causes the segmentation fault error.

I'm using Mingw x32 4.8.1 with Asio standalone 1.10.6 . I've also tested with TDM GCC 4.7.1 and Mingw x64 4.8.1. All of these under Windows produce the same segfault. There's no such issue under Linux with the latest version of GCC.

**edit:** I've just finished testing on Mingw-w64 5.2.0 (the Mingw-Builds build of it). Same problem.

I've also tested compiling this with TDM GCC 4.8.1 on a fresh virtual machine and get the same segfault. Edit: I've also now tested on a completely different machine with TDM GCC 4.8.1

In all cases I'm using `-std=c++11`, `-g` and `-Wall`. I've also compiled with `-g` and have the same result. I need the C++11 flag because I don't want a dependency on boost, just asio.

With the following code in a single `main.cpp` file there are not problems and the program seems to run as expected. However, if I put each class into it's own `*.hpp` and `*.cpp` file, I get a segfault in the `Server` classes constructor.

I further went back and put everything back into `main.cpp` and started moving each class one by one. The segfault begins occuring after the final class, `Client` is put in it's own files.

In addition, as I was putting all the classes into one file and moving them etc, I made sure that any un-needed object files weren't linked to my .exe.

This code started a lot larger but it's narrowed down to this.

**Server.hpp**

```
#ifndef SERVER_HPP_INCLUDED
#define SERVER_HPP_INCLUDED

#include <string>
#include <memory>

#define ASIO_STANDALONE
#include <asio.hpp>
using namespace asio::ip;

namespace network
{
    class Server
    {
    public:

        Server(asio::io_service& ioService, uint16_t port);

    private:

        tcp::acceptor m_acceptor;
    };
}

#endif // SERVER_HPP_INCLUDED
```

**Server.cpp**

```
#include "Server.hpp"
using namespace network;

#include <iostream>

Server::Server(asio::io_service& ioService, uint16_t port)
: m_acceptor(ioService, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(),port))
{
}
```

**Client.hpp**

```
#ifndef CLIENT_HPP_INCLUDED
#define CLIENT_HPP_INCLUDED

#include <vector>

#define ASIO_STANDALONE
#include <asio.hpp>
using namespace asio::ip;

namespace network
{
    class Client
    {
    public:

        Client(asio::io_service& ioService);

    private:

        asio::steady_timer m_timer;
    };
}

#endif // CLIENT_HPP_INCLUDED
```

**Client.cpp**

```
#include "Client.hpp"
using namespace network;

#include <iostream>

Client::Client(asio::io_service& ioService)
: m_timer(ioService)
{
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#define ASIO_STANDALONE
#include <asio.hpp>
using namespace asio::ip;

#include "Server.hpp"

int main()
{
    try
    {
        uint16_t peerRequestPort = 63000;

        asio::io_service io_service;

        network::Server server(io_service,peerRequestPort);
    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the callstack from GDB:

```
#0 00406729 asio::detail::service_registry::keys_match(key1=..., key2=...) (F:/GameDev/asio-1.10.6/asio-1.10.6/include/asio/detail/impl/service_registry.ipp:89)
#1 ??   0x0040696e in asio::detail::service_registry::do_use_service (this=0x5d2f10, key=..., factory=0x406b44 <asio::detail::service_registry::create<asio::socket_acceptor_service<asio::ip::tcp> >(asio::io_service&)>) (F:/GameDev/asio-1.10.6/asio-1.10.6/include/asio/detail/impl/service_registry.ipp:113)
#2 004068B6 asio::detail::service_registry::use_service<asio::socket_acceptor_service<asio::ip::tcp> >(this=0x5d2f10) (F:/GameDev/asio-1.10.6/asio-1.10.6/include/asio/detail/impl/service_registry.hpp:47)
#3 00403857 asio::use_service<asio::socket_acceptor_service<asio::ip::tcp> >(ios=...) (F:/GameDev/asio-1.10.6/asio-1.10.6/include/asio/impl/io_service.hpp:32)
#4 004039B3 asio::basic_io_object<asio::socket_acceptor_service<asio::ip::tcp>, true>::basic_io_object(this=0x28fe48, io_service=...) (F:/GameDev/asio-1.10.6/asio-1.10.6/include/asio/basic_io_object.hpp:182)
#5 00403B29 asio::basic_socket_acceptor<asio::ip::tcp, asio::socket_acceptor_service<asio::ip::tcp> >::basic_socket_acceptor(this=0x28fe48, io_service=..., endpoint=..., reuse_addr=true) (F:/GameDev/asio-1.10.6/asio-1.10.6/include/asio/basic_socket_acceptor.hpp:137)
#6 00401D3B network::Server::Server(this=0x28fe48, ioService=..., port=63000) (F:\GameDev\Dischan\Tests\Server.cpp:7)
#7 004018F1 main() (F:\GameDev\Dischan\Tests\main.cpp:17)
```

And finally here's the output from Dr Memory:

```
Dr. Memory version 1.8.0 build 8 built on Sep  9 2014 16:27:02
Dr. Memory results for pid 5296: "tests.exe"
Application cmdline: "tests.exe"
Recorded 108 suppression(s) from default C:\Program Files (x86)\Dr. Memory\bin\suppress-default.txt

Error #1: UNADDRESSABLE ACCESS: reading 0x00000007-0x0000000b 4 byte(s)
# 0 asio::detail::service_registry::keys_match                         [F:/GameDev/asio-1.10.6/asio-1.10.6/include/asio/detail/impl/service_registry.ipp:89]
# 1 asio::detail::service_registry::do_use_service                     [F:/GameDev/asio-1.10.6/asio-1.10.6/include/asio/detail/impl/service_registry.ipp:113]
# 2 asio::detail::service_registry::use_service<>                      [F:/GameDev/asio-1.10.6/asio-1.10.6/include/asio/detail/impl/service_registry.hpp:47]
# 3 asio::use_service<>                                                [F:/GameDev/asio-1.10.6/asio-1.10.6/include/asio/impl/io_service.hpp:32]
# 4 asio::basic_io_object<>::basic_io_object                           [F:/GameDev/asio-1.10.6/asio-1.10.6/include/asio/basic_io_object.hpp:182]
# 5 asio::basic_socket_acceptor<>::basic_socket_acceptor               [F:/GameDev/asio-1.10.6/asio-1.10.6/include/asio/basic_socket_acceptor.hpp:137]
# 6 network::Server::Server                                            [F:/GameDev/Dischan/Tests/Server.cpp:7]
# 7 main                                                               [F:/GameDev/Dischan/Tests/main.cpp:17]
Note: @0:00:00.780 in thread 7464
Note: instruction: mov    0x04(%eax) -> %eax

Error #2: LEAK 36 direct bytes 0x02530860-0x02530884 + 124 indirect bytes
# 0 replace_operator_new                       [d:\drmemory_package\common\alloc_replace.c:2609]
# 1 asio::io_service::io_service               [F:/GameDev/asio-1.10.6/asio-1.10.6/include/asio/impl/io_service.ipp:39]
# 2 main                                       [F:/GameDev/Dischan/Tests/main.cpp:15]

===========================================================================
FINAL SUMMARY:

DUPLICATE ERROR COUNTS:

SUPPRESSIONS USED:

ERRORS FOUND:
      1 unique,     1 total unaddressable access(es)
      0 unique,     0 total uninitialized access(es)
      0 unique,     0 total invalid heap argument(s)
      0 unique,     0 total GDI usage error(s)
      0 unique,     0 total handle leak(s)
      0 unique,     0 total warning(s)
      1 unique,     1 total,    160 byte(s) of leak(s)
      0 unique,     0 total,      0 byte(s) of possible leak(s)
ERRORS IGNORED:
     14 potential error(s) (suspected false positives)
         (details: C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Dr. Memory\DrMemory-tests.exe.5296.000\potential_errors.txt)
     12 potential leak(s) (suspected false positives)
         (details: C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Dr. Memory\DrMemory-tests.exe.5296.000\potential_errors.txt)
     24 unique,    24 total,   2549 byte(s) of still-reachable allocation(s)
         (re-run with "-show_reachable" for details)
Details: C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Dr. Memory\DrMemory-tests.exe.5296.000\results.txt
```

I just cannot see why I'm getting a segfault. Even after commenting out all of the meaningful code it still occurs.

---

**EDIT**

I've edited the code above to show that just the `Server` constructor appears to cause an issue and the contents of each file. (I've again ensured that only these object files are compiled and linked).

---

**EDIT 2**

I've tested this with the TDM GCC 4.7.1, Mingw Builds x64 4.8.1 and Mingw Builds x32 4.8.1. Same result for all of them.

---

**EDIT 3**

I've further reduced the code way down. Now, in `Client`, if I remove any `asio` objects that require an `asio::io_service&` to be constructed, then there is no segfault. But any of the `asio` types I've tried so far have all produced the same segfault. This isn't a problem in the `Server` class for instance, which has an `asio::acceptor`. The far out thing is that there is no instance of `Client` created, so why it affects the program and produces a segfault in `Server`s constructor is weird.

---

**EDIT 4**

I've now completely removed `Server.hpp` and `Server.cpp` and have updated `main.cpp` to this:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#define ASIO_STANDALONE
#include <asio.hpp>
using namespace asio::ip;

int main()
{
    try
    {
        uint16_t peerRequestPort = 63000;

        asio::io_service io_service;

        auto protocol = tcp::v4();
        tcp::endpoint endpoint(protocol,peerRequestPort);
        tcp::acceptor m_acceptor(io_service, endpoint);

    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I still get the segfault and the callstack reflects the lack of `Server` constructor. The segfault is still in the same place. DrMemory results look about the same as well.

Same as before, if I don't link the `Client` object file I have no issue.

---

**EDIT 5**

As requested, here is the build log from Code::Blocks

```
g++.exe -std=c++11 -Wall -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -g -I..\..\asio-1.10.6\asio-1.10.6\include -c F:\GameDev\Dischan\Tests\Client.cpp -o obj\Debug\Client.o
g++.exe -std=c++11 -Wall -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -g -I..\..\asio-1.10.6\asio-1.10.6\include -c F:\GameDev\Dischan\Tests\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
g++.exe  -o Build\Debug\Windows\Tests.exe obj\Debug\Client.o obj\Debug\main.o   -lws2_32 -lwsock32
Output file is Build\Debug\Windows\Tests.exe with size 723.02 KB
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 3 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 3 second(s))
```

---

**EDIT 6**

I'm starting to go outside of my abilities now but I've managed to track down some of the problem (and I'm learning some new stuff which is cool).

It appears that when an object which requires an `asio::io_service&` is created, it adds "services" to the `io_service`. These are static across all `io_service` instances. So, when the service request is made, there's a loop that is iterated through which appears to be a linked list of already created services. If the requested service hasn't already been created; it's then created.

This info is from the [reference for `io_service`](http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.10.6/doc/asio/reference/io_service.html) and from looking at `service_registry.ipp` (line 111).

This is done internally with a call to `service_registry::do_use_service`. The `service_registry` has a member named `first_service_` of type `asio::io_service::service*`. This first service should have a member named `next_` which is the linked list part I mentioned.

At the time of the first call to `service_registry::do_use_service` (when the `asio::acceptor` is constructed) however, the `first_service_` member has a value of `0xffffffff` which is obviously not right. So I believe that's the root of the segfault.

Why this member has the value `0xffffffff` is beyond me. It was my understanding that only old/quirky machines reserved this address for `null` pointers... but I concede I could be way off.

I did just quickly check that by doing this:

```
int* p = nullptr;
if(p)
    std::cout << "something" << std::endl;
```

and set a breakpoint to read the value. The value for `p` is `0x0`, not `0xffffffff`.

So, I set a breakpoint on the constructor for `service_registry` (`asio/detail/impl/service_registry.hpp`) and on the destructor (in case it was explicitly called somewhere) and on the three methods `do_has_service`, `do_use_service` and `do_add_service`. My thought was to try and track at what point `first_service_` gets the bad value.

I've had no luck. These are the only places which could possibly alter the value of `first_service_`.

I take this to mean that something has corrupted the stack and changed the address for `first_service_`. But, I'm only a hobbyist...

I did check that the address of the `this` pointer for the constructor was the same as the one used for the invocation of the `do_use_service` to make sure that two instances weren't created or something like that.

---

**EDIT 7**

Okay, so I've now found that if I compile with the `ASIO_DISABLE_THREADS` I no longer get a segfault!

But, this results in an exception being thrown because I'm attempting to use threads even though I've disabled them. Which I take to mean that I would be restricted to synchronous calls and no async calls. (i.e., what's the point of using asio?)

The [reference material here](http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.10.6/doc/asio/using.html) does say that `ASIO_DISABLE_THREADS`

> Explicitly disables Asio's threading support, independent of whether or not Boost supports threads.

So I take it to mean that this define stops asio from using threads regardless of boost or not; which makes sense.

Why threading would cause a problem, I don't know. I'm not keen on delving that far.

---

### I give up

<s>I give up on asio. After looking through the code and documentation, it appears to have been developed with boost in mind more-so than as a standalone library. Apparently to the point where you need to use Boost over C++11, which I just don't care to do.</s>

[Best C/C++ Network Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118945/best-c-c-network-library) looks like there's lots of alternatives.

To be honest, running my own synchronous socket calls in my own thread sounds like a better idea considering the control I'll gain. At least until asio enters the Standard Library and is implemented in Mingw-w64.

Considering that asio looks like a prime candidate to be in the standard library, or at least it's flavour, it's probably a good idea to stick with it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91860/discussion-on-question-by-neomerarcana-segfault-when-i-move-classes-to-their-own).

Comment: I'm concerned for your health

Comment: This seems very similar to your problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28427000/boostasio-triggers-a-sigsegv-in-stdtype-infooperator

Comment: @Jonathan it sounds like the same problem; however there's no more answer there than here. :(

Comment: This might be a silly comment. but shouldn't you call the run method for the io service object?

Comment: @Jonathan yes, you're absolutely right, but the code above is a result of a minimal verifiable example. The original code, since edited out, has the run method call. Just to be safe in case of some voodoo, I just tested with `run()` included and it's the same result.

Comment: Can you put `#include <asio.hpp>` as the first include in both header-files and main.cpp to see what it does?

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit i can confirm it helps.

Comment: It doesn't segfault on linux (using g++, not Wine).  But it does seems to have a wacky pointer for key2 when it gets to keys_match.  Not sure why it passes, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the segmentation fault occurs because of mismatching asio type definitions between `Server.hpp` and `Client.hpp`. In your case, this could only happen if boost changes typedefs depending on defines set by `<string>`, `<memory>` or `<vector>`.

What I suggest to try is either:

1. Include the same headers in both Server/Client.hpp and main.cpp before including asio.hpp:

   ```
   #include <string>
   #include <memory>
   #include <vector>

   #define ASIO_STANDALONE
   #include <asio.hpp>
   ```
2. Or simply include asio.hpp before any other include in your header files and remove the include from main.cpp.

Comment: Running `g++ Client.cpp Server.cpp main.cpp` doesn't lead to crash, while using `-c` and separate link command does. Can you explain this?

Comment: With which `#include`-setup? Also we should not forget that, if it's a threading issue, it can be very hard to debug and lead to all kind of weird solutions where putting f.e. a `printf` somewhere or waiting for a full-moon seems to fix it for your machine only :)

Comment: In the asker's setup.

Comment: Ok, wouldn't that only confirm that different typedefs or function declarations are being used when compiling them separately, no? Or maybe even the order of linking could change the behavior.

Comment: You mean, gcc concatenates sources before compiling them in this case?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know enough about that matter. My guess is only that a shared type has different sizes (or even different layout) in both object files, which causes the segmentation fault.

Comment: Well, that worked. I haven't awarded the bounty in case someone answers who's able to identify exactly what the different typedef's or decl are. Are they the only possible causes for this? Shouldn't it be fairly simply to track down?

Comment: I did start looking at `asio.hpp` but gave up when seeing all those `#include`'s over there :)

Comment: Yeah I might take a look and then submit an issue on asio's tracker.

Answer (score 1):

From my POV, it is a gcc bug. If you use `clang++` instead of `g++.exe`, the crash dissappears even without fiddling with `#include`'s ordering. Passing all source files to `g++` in single call also makes crash disappear. This leads me to think that there is something wrong with **gcc's COFF object files emission**, since clang uses linker from the same mingw distribution.

So, either use clang or apply workaround from @Wouter Huysentruit's answer.

Note that latest clang release (3.7.0) has another bug, not related with your problem, that makes linking fail. I had to use [nightly snapshot](http://llvm.org/builds/), which is quite stable anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. My app crashed on win_lock::lock(), but win_lock::win_lock() constructor was never called!

When added -D_POSIX_THREADS to compiler flags it simply started to work.

I use mingw-w64-i686-7.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev0 on win7